Dynamic function parameters
I have a dynamic function where I need the input parameters to be typed based on a mapping object. For example:
interface InputA {
    id: string
    test: string
}

interface InputB {
    param: string
    somethingElse: string
}

type ReturnType = Record<string, string | number | boolean>

export interface IFunctionMapper {
  A: (values: InputA) => ReturnType
  B: (values: InputB) => ReturnType
}

/**
 * Transforms params into output
 */
const FunctionMapper: IFunctionMapper = {
  A: (params) => {
    return { id: params.id }
  },
  B: (params) => {
    return { myProperty : params.somethingElse }
  },
} as const

type Keys = keyof typeof FunctionMapper
type Params = Parameters<typeof FunctionMapper[Keys]>[0]

/**
 * Get ouput using mapping function
 */
function getOutput(name: keyof typeof FunctionMapper, params: Params){

    const fn = FunctionMapper[name]

    return fn(params)
}


Type error: Argument of type 'InputA | InputB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InputA & InputB'.

See full example here:
Typescript playground example

• You should probably avoid shadowing TS-provided types like ReturnType •You're running into ms/TS#30581 and the recommended approach is a refactoring as described in ms/TS#47109. It looks like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz yes that makes sense, thanks!
